# Why does my for loop return only half the elements I expect it to?

Tags: java, for-loop, java.util.scanner, fibonacci

I would like to receive user input on n elements for the Fibonacci sequence. The scanner and calculations themselves seem to be working fine -- the input is successfully grabbed and the sequence calculated. It's even able to correctly disqualify inputs of a negative value. However, it is not actually returning 'n' elements. Curiously, I noticed that the loop consistently returns exactly half the elements requested, albeit in the correct order. If n = 20, the first 10 numbers are returned.

Here's the code:

```
public class fibonacci_input {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 1;
        int n;
            System.out.println("How many elements would you like in your Fibonacci sequence?");
            n = myObj.nextInt();
                if (n < 0)
                    System.out.println("Positive numbers only!");
                else 
                    System.out.println("Your Fibonacci sequence with " + n + " elements is:");
                    { for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
                        { 
                            System.out.print(num1 + " ");
                            int num3 = num1 + num2;
                            num1 = num2;
                            num2 = num3;
                            ++i;
                        }

                    }
            }
}
```

I'm struggling to imagine what the problem could be. I first thought it might be a problem with the test condition statement, but similar (working) solutions online seem to have their loops formatted almost identically. Is it perhaps a problem with my variable declarations? I've tried multiple changes to no avail so would appreciate another set of eyes :)

Comment: You increment “i” twice.

Comment: Look at `for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)` and `++i;` in the body. This essentially skips every 2nd element. Btw, this kind of situation can easily be resolved by stepping through the code with a debugger so you might want to acquire that useful skill early on.

Comment: What's up with the braces before and after the `for` loop after the `else`? Did you slip that `System.out.println` in the wrong place?

Comment: This worked! Thank you guys for the quick replies - you made this newbie's day a whole lot better :)

I will absolutely use debuggers going forward. Should have thought of that, so I appreciate your patience.

Federico what I was trying to do was ensure the sentence always printed before the loop, followed by the values the loop returned. Upon removing them, it seems like the extra braces are unnecessary. Good catch, you helped clean up my code a bit!

Answer (score 0):

You could just delete the second `i++;` statement in your code, this one is making the for loop run half times as expected, since the `i` variable is being incremented twice on each iteration

```
public class fibonacci_input {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 1;
        int n;
            System.out.println("How many elements would you like in your Fibonacci sequence?");
            n = myObj.nextInt();
                if (n < 0)
                    System.out.println("Positive numbers only!");
                else 
                    System.out.println("Your Fibonacci sequence with " + n + " elements is:");
                    { for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
                        { 
                            System.out.print(num1 + " ");
                            int num3 = num1 + num2;
                            num1 = num2;
                            num2 = num3;
                            //++i;
                        }

                    }
            }
}
```